# How to put max(number) condition into where clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is:

```
Select 
    res.*, s.Description as GroupSpecialty, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Period = @Q9 THEN cases END) OVER (PARTITION BY Group,Zone) as CompletedVolume 
from 
    res
```

What I need to do is to eliminate all the data where CompletedVolume < 50.

When I write `where CompletedVolume >= 50`, it says there is no column as `CompletedVolume`. When I write `MAX(CASE WHEN Period = @Q9 THEN cases END) OVER (PARTITION BY Group, Zone) >= 50`, it says

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

So I couldn't provide this condition. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You have to say, is your current query is working or giving you error. Right now you say there is some error but isnt clear on when/where. Also show us some sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query as a derived table

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (select res.*, s.Description as GroupSpecialty, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Period=@Q9 THEN cases END) OVER (PARTITION BY Group,Zone) as CompletedVolume 
  from res) DerivedTable
WHERE CompletedVolume < 50
```

Or CTE

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
select res.*, s.Description as GroupSpecialty, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Period=@Q9 THEN cases END) OVER (PARTITION BY Group,Zone) as CompletedVolume 
from res
)

SELECT * from cte
where completedvolume < 50
```

Comment: Hi, which way would be more faster you believe?

Comment: This solve the problem  `there is no column as CompletedVolume` because you cant use the alias on the same query level.

Comment: @Yokkivallayok One consideration is if you will have to resuse your query many times it is easy to reference the CTE again rather than keep repeating the code for the derived table.